# find all holomorphic $f$ with $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $0\le k \le n-1$ and $|f^{(n)}(0)|=n!$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n\ge 1$ be an integer. Find all holomorphic functions $f : D\to D$ which satisy the conditions$f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $0\le k \le n-1$ and $|f^{(n)}(0)|=n!$

I had a feeling that $az^n$ with $|a|=1$ will be all such fuctions, but I still cannot find a way to prove it. Any help is appreciated!Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

If $f\colon D \to D$ is holomorphic with $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $0 \leqslant k < n$ and $\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert = n!$, then its Taylor series starts

$$f(z) = a_n z^n + \dotsb$$

with $\lvert a_n\rvert = 1$, so

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^n}$$

is a holomorphic function on the unit disk with $\lvert g(0)\rvert = 1$. But

$$\lvert g(z)\rvert = \frac{\lvert f(z)\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert^n} \leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert z\rvert^n},$$

and therefore, taking the limit $\lvert z\rvert \to 1$, $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$. The maximum modulus principle now implies that $g$ is constant, $g \equiv a_n$, and hence $f(z) = a_nz^n$.

Comment: Why do we have $|f(z)| \le 1$? Also do you mean Liouville's Theorem, not the Maximum Modulus Principle?

Comment: @Daron: $|f(z)|\leq 1$ because the codomain of $f$ is $D$.  No, Max Mod Principle implies that $|g|$ cannot have a local max in $D$ unless $g$ is constant, so $|g(0)|=1$ and $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z$ imply $g(z)$ is constant.

Comment: @Daron $D$ is the unit disk, $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$, and $f\colon D\to D$ is the setting. Liouville's theorem is concerned with entire functions, here we have a function defined only on the unit disk. The maximum modulus principle tells us that a holomorphic function $h \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, where $\Omega$ is a domain, such that $\lvert h\rvert$ has a local maximum, is constant.

Comment: Oh thanks, I misread the question. I thought we wanted $f^{(N)}(0) = N! ~\forall N \ge n$. Which cannot occur.